# Image over graphics

Tags: java, swing

I'm developing a chess game and I created a chessboard made up of 64 `JPanel`s and I also added background color and images to them.

[image]

I have an highlighted cell (the unique cell where that pawn can move to). This is done with a graphics like this:

```
Color myColour = new Color(112,158,219,180);
Graphics g = this.getGraphics();
g.drawRect(row*75, col*75, 75, 75);
g.setColor(myColour);
g.fillRect(row*75, col*75, 75, 75);
```

As you can see when I drag the pawn above this highlighted cell the highlighting disappears and I don't want this.

How can I solve this?

Comment: You must have added a MouseMotionListener right? What have you put in your mouseReleased function?

Comment: @LittlePanda  Yes I have added mousePressed (when I click above the pawn image that cell highlights), mouseDragged and mouseReleased

Comment: for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable, voting to close

Comment: `this.getGraphics();` - If `this` is a `Component`, then this is almost certainly wrong. Paint in your `paintComponent` method. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/ etc.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is after you move pawn the exiting color values for pixels occupied by rectangle  are replaced by pawn colors.

The best solution is to load a PNG image for pawn and set those problematic pixels to have an alpha value of 0 i.e. totally transparent.
Or open your pawn image in any RGBA editor and set the pixels you want to be transparent as black.